# Initially hide first group in Vue-Formulate repeatable group

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

I'm using [Vue-Formulate's Repeatable Groups](https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/types/group/#repeatable-groups). For my requirements:

1. A group is optional to add
2. If a button is pressed to add a group, then the fields in the group must be validated
3. The form should not initially show the group; it should show the button to add a group

For example, the desired initial appearance is in the following screenshot, which I generated after clicking the "remove" / X button in the linked codesandbox:
[image]

I've mocked this up at codesandbox here: [Vue Formulate Group with Button to Start](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-group-with-button-to-start-tgyrm?file=/src/components/Reproduction.vue)

Is this possible? If so, how?

### May 2021 UPDATED WORKAROUND

In `@braid/vue-formulate@2.5.2`, the workaround below (in Research: A hack that seems to UPDATE: USED TO work) no longer works, using a slot to override the close button, save a ref, and trigger a click does. See also the related feature request at https://github.com/wearebraid/vue-formulate/issues/425.

```
<script>
  export default {
    // ... fluff omitted
    async mounted() {
      await this.$nextTick();
      if (!this.hasMessages) {
        // See also feature request at https://github.com/wearebraid/vue-formulate/issues/425
        this.$refs.closeButton.click();
      }
    },
  };
</script>

<template>
  <FormulateInput
    type="group"
    name="rangeMessages"
    :minimum="0"
    repeatable>
    <!-- See https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/types/group/#slots -->
    <template #remove="{removeItem}">
      <button ref="closeButton" @click.prevent="removeItem"/>
    </template>
  </FormulateInput>
</template>
```

### Research - Vue-Formulate's Docs

In [Vue-Formulate's docs on `input` with `type="group"`'s props and slots](https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/types/group/#props), there is a `minimum` prop. I've set that to zero, but that doesn't change the initial appearance. I do see multiple slots, but I'm not quite sure which one to use or if I could use any of them to achieve what I want; it seems like `default`, `grouping`, and `repeatable` might be useful in preventing the initial display of the first group.

### Research - Vue-Formulate's Tests

I see that [`FormulateInputGroup.test.js` tests that `it('repeats the default slot when adding more'`](https://github.com/wearebraid/vue-formulate/blob/v2.4.3/test/unit/FormulateInputGroup.test.js#L54), so the `default` slot is the content that gets repeated. According to the docs, the `default` slot also receives the `index` as a slot prop, so that could be useful.

### Research - Vue Debugger

The item which I want to initially remove is at `FormulateInputGroup > FormulateGrouping > FormulateRepeatableProvider > FormulateRepeatable > FormulateInput`:
[image: Vue debugger showing the code hierarchy of elements related to Vue Formulate with input of type="group"]

When I remove the initial item to match the desired initial layout, the group hierarchy changes to:

```
<FormulateInput><!-- the input type="group" -->
  <FormulateInputGroup>
    <FormulateGrouping/>
    <FormulateAddMore>...</FormulateAddMore>
  </FormulateInputGroup>
</FormulateInput>
```

Based on this change, I would expect that I need to modify `FormulateGrouping` to get the desired initial appearance, but I haven't found in the source what items are available to me there.

### Research: A hack that <s>seems to</s> UPDATE: USED TO work

This hack worked in v2.4.5, but as of 2.5.2, it no longer works. See top of post for an updated workaround.

> In the mounted hook, when I first render the form, I can introspect
> into the `formValues` passed to `v-model` to see if the group lacks an
> initial elements that is filled out. If so, then I can make use of a
> ref `msgs` on the `FormulateInput` of type group to then call
> `this.$refs.msgs.$children[0].$children[0].removeItem()`, which
> triggers an initial remove of the (empty) item. This is super hacky,
> so I'd prefer a better way, but it kind of works. The only problem is
> that it validates the fields when clicking on the button, before any
> input has been entered.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fair question, and Vue Formulate used to support the behavior of just using an empty array to begin with, however it became clear that it was confusing to users that their fields would not show up without an empty object `[{}]` when they bound the model, so a change was made to consider an initial value of an empty array an "empty" field and pre-hydrate it with a value. Once that initial hydration is completed however, you can easily re-assign it back to an empty array and you're good to go. This is easily done in the `mounted` lifecycle hook:

```js
...
async mounted () {
  await this.$nextTick()
  this.formData.groupData = []
}
...
```

Here's a fork of your code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-group-with-button-to-start-forked-32jly?file=/src/components/Reproduction.vue

Comment: I have nested groups, e.g. `formData = { sections: [ { type: 'typeA', messages: [{ ... }], ... }, ...]`, and `sections` are dynamically populated, and `messages` are what I'm trying to not initially show. I couldn't figure out a way to get this to work in this case, while preserving the ability to display forms whose data have been saved in the database.

Comment: I have the same problem. I also have a group nested in another one. Also the `May 2021 UPDATED WORKAROUND` from @Myer is not working as only the last button is triggered with this "hook". And when I add a new Item in the outer group the inner group is again populated with an empty item (which I do not want). Are there any ideas?

Comment: @thopaw it might be worth making a dedicated SO post for it and cross-linking it. If it contains a codepen it will be easier to chime in.

Comment: @Myerok, I posted one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67530840/use-empty-list-in-nested-groups-in-vue-formulate

Answer (score 1):

Provided solutions weren't working for me but thanks to [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63422026/10962266) I've managed to find this one:

```
mounted(){
  Vue.set(this.formData, "groupData", [])
},
```

which does same effect as

```
data(){
  formData: {
    groupData: [],
  },
},
mounted(){
  this.formData.groupData = []
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mounted() {
  this.$el.querySelector('.formulate-input-group-repeatable-remove').click();
}
```

Also works, instead of the whole thing with the slots/refs - providing you only have one repeatable group in the component.