# Hide repeatable subgroup in Vue Formulate

Tags: vue-formulate

I'm trying to hide the initial (default) first group in a repeatable group, much like what is described in [Initially hide first group in Vue-Formulate repeatable group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366497/initially-hide-first-group-in-vue-formulate-repeatable-group) except:

- I'm using a schema
- My group is a *subgroup* of another group.

Tried to follow [jpschroeder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267409/jpschroeder)'s example and logic here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-group-with-button-to-start-forked-7u682

The subgroup data is being set to an empty array in the `mounted` lifecycle hook, as recommended, but the field persists...

Comment: Try initialize the form with empty values and then in mounted hook assign required values. You can find working example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69443784/10962266)

Answer (score 0):

WAY overthinking this. While I never got the subgroup to not display using the above technique, I think I lost track of the original goal: to just keep the subgroups visualy hidden. If that's the only point, I can include a component in the schema to wrap the group in a `details` tag:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-group-with-button-to-start-forked-frzd7

While this works, it's a little cluttery. Better to figure out how to replace the `div` tag in the group template with `details`, or just use the provided classes to mimic the `details` behavior.