# Use empty list in nested groups in vue-formulate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-formulate

I am using vue with vue formulate and want to build a form with a [nested group](https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/types/group/).

As example I have a from with users (outer group) and each user can have a list of tags (inner group).

The list of tags is only an example and in my real app the nested object is more complex. For this example I could use a `,` separated list.

The problem now is, that even if I initialize the `v-model` of the form with [] it always shows 1 item. This is also discussed at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366497/initially-hide-first-group-in-vue-formulate-repeatable-group/63422026?noredirect=1#comment119354082_63422026), but without a suitable solution for me.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/thopaw/pen/ZEeWJVv) for this

As you can see, there is for with a prefilled stundets array, where the student has a name but no tags. But the form displays a tag alltough there is an empty array provided.

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "Homer",
      "tags": []
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Form displaying a tag alltough tag list is empty]

I can not use the workaround from the SO post above as I only get the last remove button as reference.

What I want is that the empty list is used and *no* input fields are rendered for the empty list.

Do anyone have an idea how to do this?
I also added `minimum="0"` to the group but this had no effect.

This would be the render state I wanted to have for the empty tag list:
[image: wanted render state]

Comment: This is because the array is empty obviously. You need a way for the user to add more tags. For tag in tags. Or have a value called tags which is watched. They can add tags by seperating them by commas. You then watch this value and split it into an array based off commas

Comment: Not really what I want. I edited my post and tried to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround to this problem is using the slots of the group an add some condition in the template.

```
<formulate-input type="group" name="..." repeatable>
  <template #repeatable="{ model, index, removeItem }">
    <div v-if="model && model.length > 0 && hasProperties(model[index])">
    ...
```

Comment: This is a complex workaround which does not solve root cause of the problem. You just need to set empty values while respecting Vue's reactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Try initialize the form empty and in mounted hook fill the form with data according to your needs. [Here is resolved fork of your codepen.](https://codepen.io/QuackingKahuna/pen/powXgOr)

```
data: {
  form: {}
},
mounted(){
  Vue.set(this.form, "students", [{name:"Homer", tags:[] }]);
}
```

Comment: This is not working with **empty** initialization as vue-formulate does some guessing for the init value of groups. Even a min="0" at the group does not prevent this.

Comment: if you need empty initialization you need to respect Vue's reactivity.
Because of this case the correct answer should be mounted(){Vue.set(this.form, "students", [{name:"Homer", tags:[] }])} - I'll edit my answer to solve this case also.